# How to sort by name side by side after du -hs

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to compare two different dirs with many many dirs inside

```
du -hs User/data/dbs/* home/common/dbs/*
```

The result is that the two dirs are shown one after another.

> 12gb User/data/dbs/file1
>
> 14gb User/data/dbs/file2
>
> 15gb User/data/dbs/file3
>
> 12gb home/common/dbs/file1
>
> 4gb home/common/dbs/file2
>
> 5gb home/common/dbs/file3

I would like to display the results by name side by side

> 12gb User/data/dbs/file1
>
> 12gb home/common/dbs/file1
>
> 14gb User/data/dbs/file2
>
> 4gb home/common/dbs/file2
>
> 15gb User/data/dbs/file3
>
> 5gb home/common/dbs/file3

I found this `| sort -n -t _ -k 2` , but it sorts them by size and name, I want sort them by name even if the size is different.

It will be great if I can leave a space between each two for easy reading.

Comment: Do you literally mean "side by side", like, multiple values per line? You can format your question to display your input literally with the `{}` button or by indenting lines by four spaces.

Comment: Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to hightlight code/data/error msgs properly. Hard to tell what you're trying to achieve with your current formatting. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

One way could be to sort the output of `find`, then apply `du`

```
find User/data/dbs/ home/common/dbs/ -print0 -type f | sort -z | xargs -r0 -I{} du -sh {}
```

Comment: The question asks about *directories* not files.

Comment: Oh right yes. I answered based on the question's snippet, where files were ultimately compared against. Find could be configured to return what the OP needs. Will update the answer for that.

Answer (score -1):

decorate-sort-undecorate with `awk`, extract the filename as key, sort by key, delete when done.

```
... | awk -F'/' '{print $NF "\t" $0}' | sort | cut -f2
```